# Deleting all files except ones mentioned in config file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Situation:**

I need a bash script that deletes all files in the current folder, except all the files mentioned in a file called "*.rmignore*". This file may contain addresses relative to the current folder, that might also contain asterisks(*). For example:

```
1.php
2/1.php
1/*.php
```

**What I've tried:**

- I tried to use `GLOBIGNORE` but that didn't work well.
- I also tried to use `find` with `grep`, like follows:

  `find . | grep -Fxv $(echo $(cat .rmignore) | tr ' ' "\n")`

Comment: Thank you, guys, for all these answers. I'll need some time read, understand, test and compare them all before i can accept one.

Comment: Well , did any of those answers helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered bad practice to pipe the exit of `find` to another command. You can use `-exec`, `-execdir` followed by the command and `'{}'` as a placeholder for the file, and `';'` to indicate the end of your command. You can also use `'+'` to pipe commands together IIRC.

In your case, you want to list all the contend of a directory, and remove files one by one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o nounset
set -o errexit
shopt -s nullglob # allows glob to expand to nothing if no match
shopt -s globstar # process recursively current directory

my:rm_all() {
    local ignore_file=".rmignore"
    local ignore_array=()
    while read -r glob; # Generate files list
    do
        ignore_array+=(${glob});
    done < "${ignore_file}"
    echo "${ignore_array[@]}"

    for file in **; # iterate over all the content of the current directory
    do
        if [ -f "${file}" ]; # file exist and is file
        then
            local do_rmfile=true;
            # Remove only if matches regex
            for ignore in "${ignore_array[@]}"; # Iterate over files to keep
            do
                [[ "${file}" == "${ignore}" ]] && do_rmfile=false; #rm ${file};
            done

            ${do_rmfile} && echo "Removing ${file}"
        fi
    done
}

my:rm_all;
```

Comment: Nicely done. Aside from my concern about iterating over a loop within a loop, I only have three nitpicky suggestions. 1st, the OP's `.rmignore` file contains files in directories, so you'll want to `globstar` on your initial for loop. 2nd, the `;` at the end of your `for` lines is redundant; perhaps it's a leftover from splitting a line that wanted a comment? 3rd, bash has `true` and `false` as builtins, so if you `local rmfile=true` and later set `rmfile=false`, you can be simply `$rmfile && echo ...`. Of course, this lends itself to more descriptive boolean variables, like `$is_target`.

Comment: I didn't know about `globstar`, thanks! I like to pus a semi-column at the end of my `for` lines, this is more a style thing (unless here is a problem with it). How would you avoid doing a double loop though?

Comment: Well .. my answer has a couple of options for that. In the first version uses `mapfile` to populate an array with exclusions, then we step through files and ignore the ones that were mapped. The other solutions populate an array, then remove things from it, then `rm` whatever remains in the array. I'd expect this to be more efficient, but hey, you never know. :)

Answer (score 1):

This line do perfectly the job

```
find . -type f | grep -vFf .rmignore
```

Comment: So you'll run `grep` once for each file being considered?  That's rather heavy if you have a lot of files.

Comment: In case that .rmignore contains `1/*.php` as OP advises, this grep will remove all files containing `1/*.php` meaning that if we have a file under 1 like `1/tutorialphp.txt` will also be removed. Grep is not suitable most of the times for files operation...

Comment: Still does not work as the OP expects. Using `grep -Fv` = Fixed String , all `*.php` files will not be caught by grep -vF and thus will be deleted. You can test it yoursefl here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcHFKQlA4NTJQZnM

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that none of the files in `.rmignore` contain newlines in their name, the following might suffice:

```
# Gather our exclusions...
mapfile -t excl < .rmignore

# Reverse the array (put data in indexes)
declare -A arr=()
for file in "${excl[@]}"; do arr[$file]=1; done

# Walk through files, deleting anything that's not in the associative array.
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do
  [ -n "${arr[$file]}" ] && continue
  echo rm -fv "$file"
done
```

Note: untested. :-)  Also, associative arrays were introduced with Bash 4.

An alternate method might be to populate an array with the *whole* file list, then remove the exclusions. This might be impractical if you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of files.

```
shopt -s globstar
declare -A filelist=()

# Build a list of all files...
for file in **; do filelist[$file]=1; done

# Remove files to be ignored.
while read -r file; do unset filelist[$file]; done < .rmignore

# Annd .. delete.
echo rm -v "${!filelist[@]}"
```

Also untested.

Warning: `rm` at your own risk. May contain nuts. Keep backups.

I note that neither of these solutions will handle wildcards in your `.rmignore` file. For that, you might need some extra processing...

```
shopt -s globstar
declare -A filelist=()

# Build a list...
for file in **; do filelist[$file]=1; done

# Remove PATTERNS...
while read -r glob; do
  for file in $glob; do
    unset filelist[$file]
  done
done < .rmignore

# And remove whatever's left.
echo rm -v "${!filelist[@]}"
```

And .. you guessed it.  Untested. This depends on `$f` expanding as a glob.

Lastly, if you want a heavier-weight solution, you can use `find` and `grep`:

```
find . -type f -not -exec grep -q -f '{}' .rmignore \; -delete
```

This runs a `grep` for EACH file being considered. And it's not a bash solution, it only relies on `find` which is pretty universal.

Note that ALL of these solutions are at risk of errors if you have files that contain newlines.

Comment: Nice Solution. each `rm` command can be replaced with `echo rm` to perform a kind of dry run before to shoot for real.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, thanks, good suggestion. I've made that change, along with improving variable names for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rsync`, you might be able to copy an empty directory to the target one, with suitable rsync ignore files.  Try it first with `-n`, to see what it will attempt, before running it for real!

Answer (score 0):

This is another bash solution that seems to work ok in my tests:

```
while read -r line;do 
exclude+=$(find . -type f -path "./$line")$'\n'
done <.rmignore

echo "ignored files:"
printf '%s\n' "$exclude"
echo "files to be deleted"
echo rm $(LC_ALL=C sort <(find . -type f) <(printf '%s\n' "$exclude") |uniq -u )  #intentionally non quoted to remove new lines
```

[Test it online here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMRGpFOG5hYTBLTTg)

Comment: @Станислав Гольденшлюгер Updated - without temp file

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may want to look at the simplest format:

```
rm $(ls -1 | grep -v .rmignore)
```